# Calculate limits with Taylor

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

I must calculate 
$$\lim_{t→1} \frac{\sin (t) − \sin (1)}{t − 1}$$

I can calculate it with L'Hospital's rule but I do not understand how to do it with taylor polynom.
I know sin is : 
$$\sin x = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1}\quad =  x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \cdots \\$$
But how do I use it here?
Thank you.

Comment: You'd have to expand $\sin(x)$ about $1$ to do it that way. You are right now expanding it about the point $0$.

Comment: You could also try substituting the expression $x+1$ using the Taylor polynomial at $0$ of $\sin(x)$

Comment: Do you really need to use Taylor's formula? This is but the definition of the derivative of $\sin t$ at $t=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by Taylor's formula you know that

$$
\sin t = \sin 1 + \cos(1)(t-1) - \frac{\sin \xi_t}{2!} (t-1)^2, \quad \xi_t \in (1,t).
$$

Back to the limit,

\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\to 1} \frac{\sin t - \sin 1}{t-1} = &\lim_{t\to 1}\frac{\sin 1 + \cos (1) (t-1) - \frac{\sin \xi_t}{2!} (t-1)^2 - \sin 1}{t-1}\\
=& \cos 1 + \lim_{t \to 1}\frac{\sin \xi_t (t-1)}{2!}
=\cos 1
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you @PierreCarre

Answer (score 3):

$\sin \, t=(\sin \, 1)+(\cos \, 1) \,(t-1) -(\sin\,1)  (t-1)^{2} /2+...$.